# No suitable user-defined conversion System:TimeSpan from System:DateTime C++ CLI

Tags: winforms, c++-cli

I need to calculate the time difference between the button presses. When I did this through change, everything worked. But I need to use classes here ((At transfer I received an error "no suitable user-defined conversion System:TimeSpan  from  System:DateTime to exists"

and

```
1>source\repos\cash2\cash2\servtime.h(14): error C2440: 'initializing': cannot convert from 'System::TimeSpan' to 'System::DateTime'
1>source\repos\cash2\cash2\servtime.h(14): note: No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called
```

I have class Servtime:

```
ref class Servtime
{
public:
    Servtime();
    DateTime starttime;
    DateTime finishtime;
    DateTime getTime();
};

DateTime Servtime::getTime() {
    DateTime timeee = finishtime.Subtract(starttime);
    return timeee;
}
```

in another place is assigned starttime

```
DateTime starttime = DateTime::Now;
```

at the click of a button

```
Servtime ^ servertime = gcnew Servtime;
    servertime->finishtime = DateTime::Now;
    servertime->starttime = starttime;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What kind of result do you expect to achieve here: `DateTime timeee = finishtime.Subtract(starttime);`? The value on the left is a point in time (`DateTime`), the value on the right is an interval (`TimeSpan`).

Comment: @defaultlocale 
starttime - moment of time on the first button.
finishtime- moment of time on the second button.
timeee - I want to get how much time passed between pressing the first and second button

Comment: In this case, `timeee` should probably be a `TimeSpan`. You'll need to change the declared return value of `Servtime::getTime()` to `TimeSpan` as well. Does this work for you?

Comment: The difference between two dates is not a date, it is span of time.  So the return value type of getTime is not correct, it must be TimeSpan.  The name of the function is not fantastic, consider getInterval().

Comment: @defaultlocale error LNK2005: "public: class System::TimeSpan __clrcall Servtime::getTime(void)" (?getTime@Servtime@@$$FQ$AAM?AVTimeSpan@System@@XZ) already defined in MyForm.obj
1>\source\repos\Cash2\Debug\Cash2.exe : fatal error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found

Comment: You put this code in a .h file.  When it gets #included multiple times by different .cpp files then you will end up with multiple definitions of Servtime::getTime().  Either write it inline in the class declaration or move it into a .cpp file.

Comment: Or add the `inline` keyword, which has the same effect as moving it inside the class declaration, but without the deep nesting implications.

Comment: The bottom line, though, is to scrap *all* of this code and use `System::Diagnostics::Stopwatch` instead, which measures elapsed time with more precision than `DateTime::Now` can give.

Comment: @HansPassant Thank you! moving to cpp helped! it works!

Comment: @defaultlocale Thank you! change the type was necessary!

Comment: @RomanRo You're welcome! Please read "[Choosing between Date types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/datetime/choosing-between-datetime)" page in the documentation. If you've managed to solve your problem you can post the solution in the answer.